# node-gyp troubles with installation

Tags: node-gyp

I'm trying to install `webworker-thread`s, a node addon that requires gyp. I followed the `gyp` instructions for setup, so far I'm still getting an error when trying to "`rebuild`":

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\webworker-threads>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\webworker-threads
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.8
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm on a Windows 7 32 bit system.
Sooo to spare some time here's my personal checklist:

Paths: node is in both user and system path. npm is in user path. Python path is set too.

- Python: 2.7.3 installed at C:\Python27
- VisualStudio C++ 2010 AND 2012 Express installed
- node version v0.10.8
- ran everything with administrator privileges
- Commands executed: npm install -g node-gyp
- npm install webworker-threads
- Then the error appears.

Do you guys by any chance notice something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance for your guidance!

Comment: I had the same problem in linux but I exported a variable LINK=g++ and the problem disapeared

Comment: export? how do you mean, export?

Comment: in linux there are environmental variables, and when you run `export LINK=g++` you tell the OS and all other softwares that the value of `$LINK` is `g++`. Here this env helps the OS to choose g++ over gcc I think

Comment: wow, ok. I'll see if there's a Windows equivalent :) thanks already

Comment: Ok tried it, no difference unfortunately :S Input is very much appreciated though!

Comment: on the error it has mentioned: `weird error` :D

Comment: have you previously installed node-gyp ?

Comment: yeah, I noticed ^^ btw I was not sure where to post my issue, it's here too: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/754

Comment: yes sure. How else would there be "gyp" errors in the upper console output if there was no gyp? ^^

Comment: i just wanted to know if it tries to install it right here or you have it installed previously.

Comment: you may ask it in irc too

Comment: ah, the installation itself works smooth. but e.g. as soon as I run "configure" it breaks

Comment: you may check the configuration options in readme or manual.

Comment: I think it's not about that, it's something global. There was a bug back in 0.10.1 with "spawn ENOENT"... and if you scroll through https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/754 you see that I also tried the hello-world app without success.
The error itself indicates that somehow spawning a child process fails. To me that issue doesn't look like it comes from a wrong configuration :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `npm install –msvs_version=2012`. This command will ask NPM to use visual studio 2012 to build.

http://www.kevgriffin.com/specifying-visual-studio-version-in-npm-installs/

Answer (score 3):

After spending a while to get this to work (for me accepted answer didn't work, for me it's just half solution) i did following:

1. Sadly, you must have visual studio (i installed express edition 2013 for DESKTOP)
2. Installed python 2.7.3 (you don't have to set any environment variables)
3. Run cmd as administrator and go to you project root (where is you package.json file)
4. First run: `npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe`
5. Then: `npm install -msvs_version=2013`

The trick is in command `npm config set python ...path_to_python_exe...` which will be provided by `npm` to dependency which needs python i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Got Windows 7 64 bit.

Did all the above but I still  got the error which was mentioned.

What worked for me was:

1. Uninstall Microsoft .NET **Frameworks** (I got more than one version)
2. Open regedit and navigating to:
    hkey_local_machine/software/Microsoft/MSBuild
3. Remove all .net versions (I got there 2 and 3.5 sub directories)
4. If You have OS 64 Bit repeat steps 2 & 3 for %WinDir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe
5. Reinstall Microsoft .NET Framework

Hope it will spare some time for you.