# NodeJS: npm install oracle, Unable to compile on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

There seems to be a lot of similar issues to compiling oracle on Windows 7/8, but most revolve around not having Python or OCI environment variables set. I've been at this for 2 days now, with no luck. Hopefully someone can provide some suggestions...

Windows 7, 32-bit
GNU bash v3.1.0(1)
Node v0.10.29
NPM v1.4.14
Oracle InstantClient 12.1.0.1.0
Python 2.7.5
Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop

I set the following variables:

```
OCI_VERSION=12  <-- Tried (10,11 and 12)
OCI_LIB_DIR=C:\InstantClient\sdk\lib\msvc\vc11
OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\InstantClient\sdk\include
PATH= ...<existing path>;C:\InstantClient\vc11;C:\InstantClient\
```

I set `npm config set python C:\Python27`

I confirmed the PYTHON environment variable was not set. (though I have tried setting it for previous attempts)

Here's what I get:

```
$ npm install oracle
-

> oracle@0.3.7 install c:\Sites\new\node_modules\oracle
> node-gyp rebuild

c:\Sites\new\node_modules\oracle>node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild \
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Sites\new\node_modules\oracle
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! oracle@0.3.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracle@0.3.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracle"
npm ERR! cwd c:\Sites\new
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\Sites\new\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here's the tail end of npm-debug.log.

```
103 info preinstall oracle@0.3.7
104 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
105 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
106 silly resolved []
107 verbose about to build c:\Sites\new\node_modules\oracle
108 info build c:\Sites\new\node_modules\oracle
109 verbose linkStuff [ false, false, false, 'c:\\Sites\\new\\node_modules' ]
110 info linkStuff oracle@0.3.7
111 verbose linkBins oracle@0.3.7
112 verbose linkMans oracle@0.3.7
113 verbose rebuildBundles oracle@0.3.7
114 info install oracle@0.3.7
115 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
116 info oracle@0.3.7 Failed to exec install script
117 info c:\Sites\new\node_modules\oracle unbuild
118 info preuninstall oracle@0.3.7
119 info uninstall oracle@0.3.7
120 verbose true,c:\Sites\new\node_modules,c:\Sites\new\node_modules unbuild oracle@0.3.7
121 info postuninstall oracle@0.3.7
122 error oracle@0.3.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
122 error Exit status 1
123 error Failed at the oracle@0.3.7 install script.
123 error This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
123 error not with npm itself.
123 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
123 error     node-gyp rebuild
123 error You can get their info via:
123 error     npm owner ls oracle
123 error There is likely additional logging output above.
124 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
125 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracle"
126 error cwd c:\Sites\new
127 error node -v v0.10.29
128 error npm -v 1.4.14
129 error code ELIFECYCLE
130 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Though I'm using the GNU bash that came with git, I have also tried through Windows Command Prompt with the same results.

I posted this on the project's github page, yesterday, but was hoping to get a broader audience that might be aware of what I'm missing to compile this module.

Comment: Are you following the [oficial installation instructions](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/blob/master/INSTALL.md#detailed-installation-instructions)?

Comment: Yes. That is where I started. I re-downloaded the Oracle InstantClient Basic and SDK packages recommended, and the above environment variables/path are directly from the documentation (with the path names corrected for my system). Unfortunately, this is the extent of the detail provided yet I still get the above error.)

Comment: I had the same problem trying to follow the exact same instructions. It took a couple days for me too to finally install it. What I did and worked pretty well for me: my attempts trying to install this module with `VisualStudio 2010` didn't work, so I unistalled it, removed all `Microsoft Visual C++*` previously installed and installed `VisualStudio 2012 Express for Desktop`, like you did. Then, I told npm to use `VisualStudio 2012` with the command `npm install –msvs_version=2012`. Hope that works for you.

Comment: I just removed ALL Microsoft Visual * from control panel, rebooted, re-installed VS 2012 Express for Desktop (rebooted again) and it's still giving me the same error. (and I tried used `npm install oracle --msvs_version=2012` and just `npm install oracle`.

Comment: That's a bummer. It worked for me. I found some links that might be helpful, if you didn't try them yet: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23458908/2241993), [here](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/issues/159) and [here](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/issues/95). Let me know if you have success with one of them.

Comment: No good. Tried `npm cache clean`, and I'm not behind a proxy. Not getting any python errors, and tried removing old .NET registry entries and re-installing 4.5, but no luck.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. You could try to ask the [node-oracle top answeres](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node-oracle/topusers). Maybe they can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you are comfortable in C#, an option is to call .NET in-process and leverage .NET's mature database ecosystem. Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33005452/30246).